# What is best way to delete records all parents and childs in salesforce

Tags: apex, delete

I have a use case where i have to clean up of data. I want to delete around 1000 records out of 10,000 records. Is there any way i can delete A->all lookups and All Master, then all lookups-> all masters etc. I want to clean every record in this way. thanks

Comment: Master-Detail, or Lookup? There's a difference.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have both type of relationships on objects